# Why TypeScript is not complaining about this code?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I have the following code:

```
interface Context {
  id: number;
}

interface FunctionStep<T> {
  (input?: any): (context: T) => (prevStepOutput?: any) => any;
}

function pipe<T extends Record<string, any>>(callbacks: Array<FunctionStep<T>>) {
  return (context: T) => (...args: any) => {};
}

const context: Context = {
  id: 12,
}

const clean: FunctionStep<number> = () => (context) => () => {}

pipe<Context>(clean())(context);
```

I would expect TypeScript to complain because I'm passing a `FunctionStep<number>` where it should be expecting a `FunctionStep<Context>`. Why instead everything appears as correct?

Test sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-cookies-k51mb

If that's the expected behavior, how could I restrain the `FunctionStep` passed to `pipe` to be those of the correct `context` type?

Comment: Which line do you expect an error on? You are not passing a `FunctionStep<number>`, because although `clean` has that type, you are passing `clean()`, not the function itself.

Comment: @kaya3 yes, you're right, but shouldn't it complain that not a `FunctionStep` is being passed? as what's getting into `pipe` is the result of calling `clean()`. And any idea about how to model the intended behavior then? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Well, it does complain about that. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwQB5mQbwChllgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5CBfQw0SWRFAMRogEYYJgDKkAA4AeACoA+AsWQAKUFJpgA-FTggAngEoqqhJki4qco8gC8S1VKgQAbpIhSA8ls069hrYOyPoGrByEMEIiYiDIUsBSEPLIOJAgZADOyABKEOZQZDKZYFCgAOYANCGGCgpmcAA2jQyIANaZVACCUFBwBjKCwqIS0vJ1tkQkLmA0UHFmFmnWQY4AdBtwUOWdNcb2Svhs4ZzmICXIZ5ZgVBhYuPbKJORUAIwATJXsp5gXCI0QfRUIYxUaeGS0RjQJR2NSrNRXNLw1Two6cBJJGR3a71f6AkAooyLe5gIzMIA) The error also occurs in your own link. I'm not sure what your intended behaviour is, though.

Comment: I have exactly wanted error in this code. Dont see an issue.

Answer (score 0):

`FunctionStep<T>` expects a generic type, this means that `T` can be anything.
So there is no error in calling `FunctionStep<Context>`.

If FunctionStep should expect a Context there is no reason to use a generic type, it should be a simple parameter. You can also limit what T can be using `FunctionStep<T extends X | Y>`.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit more and taking into account @kaya3 suggestion, I found a way of making it behave as intended:

```
interface Context {
  id: number;
}

interface FunctionStep<T> {
  (context: T): (prevStepOutput?: any) => any;
}

function pipe<T extends Record<string, any>>(callbacks: Array<FunctionStep<T>>) {
  return (context: T) => (...args: any) => {};
}

const context: Context = {
  id: 12,
}

const clean = (): FunctionStep<Context> => (context) => () => {}

pipe<Context>(clean())(context);
```

Comment: I'm curious what 'suggestion' I made; I only asked questions. It's still not clear to me what the actual problem is, since Typescript makes the same complaint about both this and the original code.

Comment: The fact that I wasn't passing the function but actually, the result of calling the function.

Comment: OK, but your question was "why is Typescript not complaining about this code?", and this edit doesn't cause Typescript to complain about anything new; there was the same type error in the original code.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't complaining about the right type of the generic context, with that edit, if you try to use `const clean = (): FunctionStep<number> => (context) => () => {}` it will complain, which was the main goal.